# differentiation of 1-norm of a vector

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

Assume you want to find the minimum of the following expression

$\|x\|_1 + \alpha \|Ax-b\|_2$ where $x\in R^N$.

So basically I want to calculate the derivative of $\|x\|_1$ so I could finally set the equation to zero and solve for $x^*$.

What is the best approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: To minimize this expression you will need to use an iterative algorithm. The function is non differrentiable, so you can't just set the gradient equal to 0. Your problem is similar to the famous Lasso problem.

Answer (score 10):

The differentials of the Manhattan and Frobenius norms are 
$$\eqalign{
 d\,\|X\|_1 &= {\rm sign}(X) : dX \cr
 d\,\|X\|_2 &= \frac{X}{\|X\|_2} : dX \cr
}$$
where the sign function is applied element-wise, and the colon represents the Frobenius product, i.e. $\,\,A\!:\!B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$

Letting $Y=(AX-B)$, the current function and its differential can be written as 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \|X\|_1 + \alpha\|Y\|_2 \cr\cr
 df &= {\rm sign}(X) : dX + \frac{\alpha Y}{\|Y\|_2} : dY \cr
    &= {\rm sign}(X) : dX + \frac{\alpha Y}{\|Y\|_2} : A\,dX \cr
    &= {\rm sign}(X) : dX + \frac{\alpha A^TY}{\|Y\|_2} : dX \cr
}$$
Since $df=\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}:dX\big)\,$ the derivative is
$$\eqalign{
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= {\rm sign}(X) + \frac{\alpha A^TY}{\|Y\|_2} \cr
  &= {\rm sign}(X) + \frac{\alpha A^T(AX-B)}{\|AX-B\|_2} \cr
}$$
This is slightly different than the accepted answer because $B$ appears in the numerator.  But I cannot spot the problem in Nicolas' derivation.

Comment: I forgot the coefficients $b_j$ in my derivative (I will edit this), so we have the same answer, yours is just more compact thanks to the matrix notations.

Answer (score 6):

Let us calculate the derivative of the map $x\mapsto\|x\|_1$.

For all $x=\left(x_1,\ldots,x_N\right)\in\mathbb{R}^N$, one has
$$\|x\|_1=|x_1|+\ldots+|x_N|$$
so that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(x\mapsto\|x\|_1\right)=\frac{x_j}{|x_j|}\quad\quad\quad 1\leq j\leq N$$
provided that $x_j\neq 0$.
Whence
$$\mathrm{d}\left(x\mapsto\|x\|_1\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{x_j}{|x_j|}\mathrm{d}x_j.$$

Now we compute the derivative of the map $x\mapsto\|Ax-b\|_2$.

If $A=\left(a_{ij}\right)\in\mathrm{M}_{M\times N}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, one writes for all $b=\left(b_1\ldots b_M\right)^T\in\mathbb{R}^M$
$$\|Ax-b\|_2=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{ik}x_k-b_i\right)^2}$$
and then
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(x\mapsto\|Ax-b\|_2\right)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{ik}x_k-b_i\right)a_{ij} }{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{ik}x_k-b_i\right)^2}}\quad\quad\quad 1\leq j\leq N.$$
Hence, one has
$$\mathrm{d}\left(x\mapsto\|Ax-b\|_2\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{ik}x_k-b_i\right)a_{ij} }{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{ik}x_k-b_i\right)^2}}\mathrm{d}x_j.$$

Now your optimization problem : in $\left(\mathbb{R}^N\right)^*$ provided with the base $\mathcal{B}=\left(\mathrm{d}x_1,\ldots,\mathrm{d}x_N\right)$ (the natural dual basis), we write
$$\sum_{j=1}^{N}\left(\frac{x_j}{|x_j|}+\alpha \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{ik}x_k-b_i\right)a_{ij} }{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{ik}x_k-b_i\right)^2}}\right)\mathrm{d}x_j=0.$$
As $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis, each coefficient in the precedent formula must be zero, and thus, one must find $x_1,\ldots,x_N\in\mathbb{R}$ in order to fulfill the equality
$$\frac{x_j}{|x_j|}+\alpha \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{ik}x_k-b_i\right)a_{ij} }{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{ik}x_k-b_i\right)^2}}=0\quad\quad\quad 1\leq j\leq N.$$

To complete this answer, as pointed out by littleO, the original function is not differentiable everywhere, so one way to answer to the optimization problem is to find extrema with the differential (where it exists) and then check at hand the other points.

Comment: Completed my answer. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: These functions are non differrentiable, so what do you mean by differentiating them?

Comment: The norms are differentiable except at the origin (I did point it out for the norm $\|.\|_1$).